# change input box value according to variable php and html

Tags: php, html

I am making a PHP project and am trying to change an input boxes value according to a PHP variable, how would I do this? So far, when I try to change the input boxes value it just changes the value to the name of the variable.

Here's the html for that section:

````
    echo '       

        <html>
<title>Ramen</title>
<body>
    <h1>
    <p>Welcome to NoteBook!</p>
<form method="post">
<p>File Name:<input type="text" name="fname"></p>
    <p>Type Here:<input type="text" name="content" id="TextBox" value="<?php echo $value; ?>"><p>
<p>Save:<input type="submit" value="Save"></p>
</form>
<form method="post">
<p>File to Open: <input type="text" name="filename"></p>
<input type="submit" value="Open">
</form>
    </h1>
</body>
<style>
body{
background-color:#66b3ff;
}
p{
    margin-left:30px;
}
h1{
    background-color:white;
    height:600px;
    border-radius:1px;
    font-size:18px;
    font:italic;
}
#TextBox{
height:500;
width:700;
}
{
</style>

    </html>```
````

Answer (score 0):

`$value` doesn't appear to be being set anywhere.
I'm also a little confused as to why you have two `<form>`s.

As a starter, you need to parse the values coming in from the form, for example:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST["filename"]) { // The $_POST variables are set using the name element of the <input> tag
    $value = $_POST["filename"]
  }
?>
```

You would likely want to do some more validation on the content of `$_POST["value"]` before accepting it.

Perhaps take a look at [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp) to get you started.

Comment: Oops! Cut and paste error on my part there. Correcting the reply.

Comment: I did declare the variable, but I just didn't show it in my question

Answer (score 0):

I leave you a possible example with explanation.

Besides, I have adapted the HTML structure a bit, since it has serious formatting problems. I advise you to read the manual on how to use the labels.

I added the name attribute to the submit, in order to know if the form is defined:

`<input type="submit" name="save_data" value="Save">`

**Example:**

```
<?php
    // reset ¡important! (avoid warning <b>Warning</b>:  Undefined variable etc..)
    $file_name = $content = $txt_content = '';

    // Recomended to check if the form is define
    if (isset($_POST['save_data'])) {
        // Get the inputs data
        $file_name = $_POST['fname'] ?? '';
        $content = $_POST['content'] ?? '';
        // You can use textarea
        $txt_content = $_POST['txt_content'] ?? '';

        // Data is true
        if ($file_name && $content && $txt_content) :
            // Do somenting (ex: save it in DB)
            //
            //
            $success = "Save correctly: $file_name";
        // Data is empty (optional)
        else :
            $error = 'Te fields are empty.';
        endif;
    }
?>   
<html lang="en-EN">
<head>
    <title>Ramen</title>
    <style>
        body{
            background-color:#66b3ff;
        }
        p {
            margin-left:30px;
        }
        
        .wrapper {
            background-color:white;
            height:600px;
            border-radius:1px;
            font-size: 1rem;
            font:italic;
            padding: 1rem;
        }
        textarea {
            height:200px;
            width:400px;
        }
        .error {
            color: red;
        }
        .success {
            color: green;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>   
<div class="wrapper"> 
    <h1>Welcome to NoteBook!</h1>
    <form method="post">
        <lable for="fname">File Name:</lable>
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="<?php echo $file_name; ?>"></p>

        <label for="content">Type Here:</label>
        <input type="text" name="content" id="content" value="<?php echo $content; ?>">

        <!-- for the content you could use the textarea tag -->
        <textarea name="txt_content"><?php echo $txt_content; ?></textarea>

        <input type="submit" name="save_data" value="Save">
        <?php if (isset($error)) echo '<p class="error">' . $error . '</p>'; ?>
        <?php if (isset($success)) echo '<p class="success">' . $success . '</p>'; ?>
        
    </form>    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```